# Running an angular app using node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a html page and a serviceController.js, I need to automatically run the app through node js. Sorry for the naive question but am unable to run it. My serviceController.js looks like this :

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('serviceController', ['$scope', '$interval','$http',  function($scope, $interval, $http) 
{  $scope.service1 = {//and so on..
}
```

I was following an example and I have tried the following: created a package.json :

```
{  "name": "express-html", 
 "version": "0.0.1", 
 "dependencies": {    
"express": "^4.11.0"  
}}
```

My server.js looks like this :

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
app.get('/',function(req,res){  
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html')); 
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

But, when I try starting the application from terminal using: node server.js. I get the following error :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) 
{ var app = angular.module("app", []);                             
^ReferenceError: angular is not defined    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dem/Desktop/frontend/task3/serviceController.js:1:81)    
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)    
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)    
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)    
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)    
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)    
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)    
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)    
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dem/Desktop/frontend/task3/server.js:5:19)    
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Please guide!

Comment: Please check angular.js file is included and ng-app is set inside html page.

Comment: app.use("/", express.static(__dirname)); Use this in place of  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));

Comment: How are you adding your angular.js lib? by linking cdn your by bower?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - you mean serviceController.js right? yes, i have included that and <body ng-app="app"> is set

Comment: @NiteshRana - Yes, adding the line you suggested worked. If you like, you can post it as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname)); Use this in place of

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));

Answer (score 1):

Update server file to serve a static directory 
like `app.use(express.static('dirPath'))`
For more detail visit [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)